# Is a SuperServer 6017R-72RFTP Debian-compatible?

Tags: linux, debian, hardware-compatibility

Can I install Debian on Supermicro SuperServer 6017R-72RFTP?

I was investigating Supermicro webpage and at some point it got confusing because I was not sure do I and for I have all necessary drivers, e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 Server ...

Comment: "Can I install Debian on Supermicro machine?" I don't see why not?

Comment: Most of our test and production servers are Debian on Supermicro hardware. So you definitely can install it. Of course, different hardware will have different requirements, new stuff may require a newer kernel than in 12.04 LTS (or Debian stable).

Comment: If you're unsure, please edit your question to include details of the *specific* machine you're looking at.

Comment: @derobert Thanks. I have added specific machine.

Comment: @Sylca OK, I've rewritten your question to be just about the one machine—if feel free to revert if you're unhappy about that, but beware that questions which aren't focused or alternatively are more about starting a discussion than asking a specific question are likely to be closed.

Comment: @derobert You are right. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several Supermicro Servers that are running Debian Squeeze (6.x) and Wheezy(7.x). I have never had *any* problems with hardware compatibility. Honestly these days, with modern Debian releases, I haven't found much that I can't get it to run on.

The actual server motherboard and embedded hardware (NICs, Root Ports, RAM controller, SATA I/O, etc.) should be fine.  When checking out basic compatibility some things that you may want to verify are:

- CPU
- RAID controllers
- Video Card(s)

These are usually specified and are things that could provide compatibility issues. Several of my Supermicro Debian servers do have RAID controllers and I had no problems with the factory drivers.

I think you should be pretty safe with a new server and Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Yeah, listed drivers are the ones that I'm worried about.

Comment: Just found the server on serversDirect, they were down earlier when i checked. I don't see anything there that would scare me at all. The machine looks solid imho.

Comment: OK, I'll try to install Debian today and see what happens. Thank you on your opinions, they were very helpful for me.

Comment: It seems to be that Debian is compatible with my machine. Thanks for all!!!